# Load main page every 5 minutes in java

Tags: java, timer

My program loads a web page. I try to load first page again after 5 minutes if users do not use program. How can I do it?
I tried this:

```
TimerTask timerTask=new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            wv.getEngine().load("http://www.google.com");
            update();
        }
    };

    timer=new Timer();
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) of `Timer`:

> `schedule(TimerTask task, long delay)`: 
>   Schedules the specified task for execution after the specified delay.

`Timer#schedule()` will not execute tasks at a given interval, it will only execute once. To have tasks executed every 5 minutes, you need to use `Timer#scheduleAtFixedRate()`.

> `scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, Date firstTime, long period)`: 
>   Schedules the specified task for repeated fixed-rate execution, beginning at the specified time.

The `AtomicBoolean` is included since you mentioned something about conditionally reloading the page.

**ReloadTask**

```
public class MyTask extends TimerTask {
    private final AtomicBoolean shouldReload = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public synchronized void reload() {
        this.shouldReload.set(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(shouldReload.getAndSet(false)) {
            wv.getEngine().load("http://www.google.com");
            update();
        }
    }
}
```

**Run it**

```
final Timer timer = new Timer();
final MyTask task = new MyTask();
task.reload();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1000, 5 * 60 * 1000);
```

**At any point in your code**

```
task.reload();
```

Comment: @amir Please accept the answer if it has helped you.

Comment: It doesnt work.